# Receive UDP broadast with no address assigned to interface with Linux/C/IPv4

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, broadcast

While developing a small DHCP client, I managed to *send* broadcasts on a specific interface by binding to IFADDR_ANY and setting SO_BROADCAST and SO_BINDTODEVICE, and I can see replies from the DHCP server.

Unfortunately, unless that interface has an address configured, my application doesn't receive any packets. That makes writing a DHCP client rather pointless.

**QUESTION:** How can I receive IPv4 UDP broadcasts on an interface that has not assigned an address?

I'm aware of RAW sockets, but I'd like to avoid using them.
If sending was impossible, I would just accept that no UDP is possible unless addresses are configured, but as sending works fine and just receiving does not, I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Here's minimal code:

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in src = { .sin_family=AF_INET, .sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY, .sin_port=htons(68) };

    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);

    const int on=1;
    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));

    struct ifreq ifr;
    memset(&ifr, '\0', sizeof(ifr));
    snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), argv[1]);
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr);
    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, (void *)&ifr, sizeof(ifr));

    bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&src, sizeof(src));

    char buf[512];
    ssize_t res = recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, NULL, 0);
    printf("res=%zi\n", res);

    return 0;
}
```

I run this through "sudo strace", and it stops in recvmsg() forever, even if I can watch broadcast UDP on port 68 in wireshark.

Comment: Yeah, you missed to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: To get us to debug the problem, 1) post the code 2) post the actual input from the DHCP server (a DHCP is a server, not a client) 3) post the actual output to the DHCP server.  4) post the code.  (1 an 4 are repeats because that is so critical.

Comment: Seen so many questions, and then I go all wrong for the first I ask myself - sorry. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. "reverse path filtering" was activated, causing all IPv4 packets which would take a different return path (or which have no route) to be dropped.
If no address is configured for that interface, every packet gets dropped.

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
```

did the trick.